# How to model branches/GitFlow in CA Harvest?

Tags: harvest-scm

I've spent a day to read Harvest docs here: https://docops.ca.com/ca-harvest-scm/13-0/en/using/manage-changes-in-the-repository-and-workspace

I feel this tool is designed for mainframe only:
1. Promoting packages from lower stage to higher are like promote code from lower environments to higher in mainframe.
2. Code is re-compiled in each stage like mainframe.

Seems its branch is at the item/package level, doesn't like a branch in modern SCM tool. How can I model a normal branch strategy like GitFlow in this tool? If I can't create branches, than how can I support parallel development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harvest is not for mainframe development.It is meant for distributed systems.

I will explain methods of parallel development when using one project and multiple projects

Single project :

package is the smallest unit of change.
Multiple branches can be created from the same base version and can be assigned to two developers with each developer owing a bracnh

FIle1.java -BASE version
File1.java - o.1.1 -package 1 - developer 1
File1.java - 0.2.1 -package 2 - developer 2

When both of them complete their changes ,they can merge back their changes to the package using a process called concurrent merge

If conflicts exist ,merge engineer will step into and resolve the merge activity

**Across Projects:
---------------**

Say for example ,two projects exist
proj1
proj2

A snapshot can be taken from the source code baselined to proj1
This snapshot can be baselined to proj2.

proj1 and proj2 work can continue in parallel development mode

and when one of the project is completed earlier and you would want to merge the changes to proj2 ,you can do using a process called Cross Project Merge.

This is a short explanation
If you need more detailed explanation,please reach out to CA Support team .

Regards,
Balakrishna.

Comment: So parallel development or branching can be done at the package level or project level. I can visualize proj1 and proj2 as two branches (this is the same concept as in ClearCase UCM sibling projects), but how can I see the "branch" at the package level?

Comment: Is there a good document like Git Flow, http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, describes a working branching strategy for CA-SCM/Harvest?

Comment: HI Jirong Hu, Apologies for the late answer. Please reach out to us on sccm harvest communities where visibility is high and you will be answered https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-harvest

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is using a sibling project to model the branch.